# I'm trying to make a custom validator for my formGroup in Angular. But I can't implement the custom validator in the formGroup

Tags: angular, validation

I'm trying to make a custom validator for my formGroup in Angular. But I can't implement the custom validator in the formGroup.

this is what I have :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, Validator, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

// custom validator to check if password confirmation matches
import { MustMatch } from "../../customValidators/mustMatch";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-change-password',
  templateUrl: './change-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./change-password.component.scss']
})
export class ChangePasswordComponent implements OnInit {
  //formGroup met 2 formControlls, 1 voor gebruiekrsnaam en 1 voor wachtwoord
  changePasswordForm = new FormGroup({
    currentPass: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
    newPass: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
    confirmPass: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, MustMatch('newPass', 'confirmPass')])),
  }, {

    }

    );

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I get a error  at "MustMatch('newPass', 'confirmPass')" that says : TS2322: Type '(formGroup: FormGroup) => void' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
Type'void' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors'.

This is the custom validator :

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

// custom validator to check that two fields match
export function MustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
    const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

    if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.mustMatch) {
      // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
      return;
    }

    // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
    if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
      matchingControl.setErrors({ mustMatch: true });
    } else {
      matchingControl.setErrors(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Angular checks the validation of your form, it expects validators to return a *ValidatorFn* not to just directly acts on your controls (that's why void isn't an expected signature).

So you need to change the end of your custom validator to :

```
// set error on matchingControl if validation fails
    if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
      return { mustMatch: true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
```

And as you are checking several controls from your formGroup and not only your confirmPass control, you need to attach your validator to the formGroup :

```
changePasswordForm = new FormGroup({
    currentPass: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
    newPass: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
    confirmPass: new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validators.required,])),
  },  [MustMatch('newPass', 'confirmPass')]);
```

Comment: It still doesn't work now. I have this in the html file now :
<span *ngIf="f.confirmPass.errors.MustMatch">Passwords must match</span>

Everything else is edited to what you said

Comment: We moved the validator to the parent formGroup so you won't find any errors on the 'confirmPass' control with f.confirmPass.errors. Secondly, the errors object of a control includes the return result of your validators, not your validators. As the previous returned object is '{mustMatch: true}, your html should be '*ngIf="f.errors.mustMatch'

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 ...
      changePasswordForm = new FormGroup({
        currentPass: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
        newPass: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
        confirmPass: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
      }, { validators: MustMatch('newPass', 'confirmPass')});

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick run down. For those who are new, I'll break down all the steps, so apologies if there's some extra info you don't need here:

Step 1 - Build the form and add the validators:

```js
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,) { }

  myNewForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    myInput1:new FormControl("",[ // you can also add a default value for your input field here instead of ""
      Validators.required,
      Validators.maxLength(5),
      this.myCustomValidator()
    ],
    ),        
  });
```

You'll also need to add the following imports to your TS doc:

import {AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, ValidatorFn, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

Don't forget to add all the necessary imports into your module as well.

Step 2 - define your custom validator. The validator below will see if the input value in the 'myInput1' form is equal to the string "test"

```js
  myCustomValidator(): ValidatorFn {  
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null =>  
    this.myNewForm?.get('myInput1')?.value === 'test' ? null : {myErrorMessage: control.value};
  }
```

Step 3 - Add your HTML

```html
        <div [formGroup] = "myNewForm">
            <mat-form-field  appearance="fill" style="width:100%">
                <mat-label>Test Field</mat-label>
                <input class="form-control" matInput id = "myInput1" formControlName="myInput1" placeholder="name..." required/>
                <mat-error>
                    <app-error-message
                        [control]="myNewForm.controls['myInput1'].errors"
                    ></app-error-message>
                </mat-error>            
            </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Step 4 - Define the custom error messages in the 'app-error-message' component. This will be a separate component that will need to be imported into the component you're working in:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-error-message',
  templateUrl: './error-message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-message.component.scss'],
})
export class ErrorMessageComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() control: ValidationErrors | null;

  errors: string[] = [];
  errorMessages: string[] = [];

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.errorMessages = [];

    if (this.control !== null) {
      this.errors = Object.keys(this.control);
      this.errors.forEach((error) => {
        this.errorMessages.push(this.getErrorMessage(this.control, error));
      });
    }
  }

  getErrorMessage(error: ValidationErrors | null, key: string): string {
    switch (key) {
      case 'myErrorMessage':
        return 'add custom message here'; 
// you can add extra cases to have extra messages     

      default:
        return 'Unknown Error';
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!